# Making a tag view programmatically in Cocoa Swift Macos

Tags: macos, cocoa, tags, swift4.2

I need to replicate the tag view popover that finder has.[Finder tag view] https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCufn.png, but with a difference, the tag view, need to be inside of an scrollview with the purpose of allow only 5 visible tag lines

I started with a NSTextView, but when i add a button inside textView, the text is always behind the tags, that is to say, the tags cover the text that is written. https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeJWy.png

How can i do something similar to finder?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I try with NSTokenField, but something went wrong because the scrollview doesn't scroll: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sweDN.png

That's my code:

```
class SearchTagView:NSScrollView {


lazy var tokenizer: NSTokenField = {
    let tokenizer = NSTokenField(string: "")
    tokenizer.isEnabled = true
    tokenizer.isSelectable = true
    tokenizer.isEditable = true
    tokenizer.tokenStyle = NSTokenField.TokenStyle.squared
    tokenizer.font = NSFont(name: FontList.montserrat(weight: .medium).value, size: 13)
    tokenizer.textColor = .red
    tokenizer.cell?.image = nil
    tokenizer.cell?.wraps = true
    tokenizer.cell?.isScrollable = false
    tokenizer.usesSingleLineMode = false
    tokenizer.autoresizingMask = [.width, .height]
    return tokenizer
}()



override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
    super.init(frame: frameRect)
    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    addSubview(tokenizer)
    tokenizer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tokenizer.pinToSuperView()
}


override func viewDidMoveToSuperview() {
    super.viewDidMoveToSuperview()
    documentView = tokenizer
}


required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

}

Remark:

The Scrollview is pinned to superview in leading, trailing and top, and it has a height between 35 and 75 in with constraints:

```
 NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
   searchTagView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor),
            searchTagView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            searchTagView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
            searchTagView.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant:35),
            searchTagView.heightAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualToConstant:70),
    ])
```

Comment: Have you looked at NSTokenField?

Comment: @Marek H How can I change the color of tokens?. Thanks

Comment: // This method allows you to change the style for individual tokens as well as have mixed text and tokens.
- (NSTokenStyle)tokenField:(NSTokenField *)tokenField styleForRepresentedObject:(id)representedObject;

Comment: @MarekH Could you give me an example please?

Comment: 1. Don't subclass scrollview. Subclass NSView and set it as documentView of scrollview. 2. Subclass NSTokenField and overrider tokenField: styleForRepresentedObject: 3. If you want sizeable NSTokenField look for keywords "flexible height nstextfield" - NSTokenField is a subclass of NSTextField.